# SSH with Kerberos authentication

Tags: ssh, authentication, kerberos

I am encountering the following problem: I am trying to connect from a client VM to a server VM using SSH with Kerberos authentication, but SSH still asking me for password. Obviously, I modified the `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file, on server side, to enable: `GSSAPIAuthentication yes` and `GSSAPICleanupCredentials yes`. On the client machine I did the same in the `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` file. 
About Kerberos: I added a principal, using kadmin.local, called `host/server@SERVER.COM` where "server" is the hostname of the server machine and SERVER.COM is the name of the realm. Once creating that principal for SSH service, I used the `ktadd -k command` to add the keytab file (to be clear, SSH server and Kerberos server are on the same machine) located at `/etc/krb5.keytab`. The output of `sudo klist -ke /etc/krb5.keytab` is

```
Keytab name: FILE:/etc/krb5.keytab
KVNO Principal
---- --------------------------------------------------------------------------
   1 host/server.com@SERVER.COM (aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96) 
   1 host/server.com@SERVER.COM (aes128-cts-hmac-sha1-96) 
   1 host/server.com@SERVER.COM (aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96) 
   1 host/server.com@SERVER.COM (aes128-cts-hmac-sha1-96) 
   1 host/server.com@SERVER.COM (aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96) 
   1 host/server.com@SERVER.COM (aes128-cts-hmac-sha1-96) 
   1 michele@SERVER.COM (aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96) 
   1 michele@SERVER.COM (aes128-cts-hmac-sha1-96) 
   1 host/server@SERVER.COM (aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96) 
   1 host/server@SERVER.COM (aes128-cts-hmac-sha1-96)
```

So, the creation of keytab was OK. Well, on the server machine I also added a user named michele (even listed in the list above and added as a principal obviously) and the same was created on the client machine. I typed the ssh command in debug mode `sudo /usr/sbin/sshd -p 9001 -D -dd`  on both client and server and I get the following:

1)For server side:

```
debug2: load_server_config: filename /etc/ssh/sshd_config
debug2: load_server_config: done config len = 370
debug2: parse_server_config: config /etc/ssh/sshd_config len 370
debug1: sshd version OpenSSH_7.5, OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016
debug1: private host key #0: ssh-rsa SHA256:Uu0sgKAMRqoKGBxZ+pLywmfCH8Fby+3p/rgJ5TSn45w
debug1: private host key #1: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:ycCOVyRMzFst+8uwleIs1VtvhsoN+3GZE/Tjj7i/MlA
debug1: private host key #2: ssh-ed25519 SHA256:I1PpnUol1xHFKTiM+yTGN0C3h6PSjgo34VjkFtUH6Uk
debug1: rexec_argv[0]='/usr/sbin/sshd'
debug1: rexec_argv[1]='-p'
debug1: rexec_argv[2]='9001'
debug1: rexec_argv[3]='-D'
debug1: rexec_argv[4]='-dd'
debug1: Set /proc/self/oom_score_adj from 0 to -1000
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Bind to port 9001 on 0.0.0.0.
Server listening on 0.0.0.0 port 9001.
debug2: fd 4 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Bind to port 9001 on ::.
Server listening on :: port 9001.
debug1: Server will not fork when running in debugging mode.
debug1: rexec start in 5 out 5 newsock 5 pipe -1 sock 8
debug1: inetd sockets after dupping: 3, 3
Connection from 192.168.56.5 port 60904 on 192.168.56.4 port 9001
debug1: Client protocol version 2.0; client software version OpenSSH_7.5p1 Ubuntu-10ubuntu0.1
debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.5p1 Ubuntu-10ubuntu0.1 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.5p1 Ubuntu-10ubuntu0.1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug2: Network child is on pid 4541
debug1: permanently_set_uid: 122/65534 [preauth]
debug1: list_hostkey_types: ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519 [preauth]
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent [preauth]
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received [preauth]
debug2: local server KEXINIT proposal [preauth]
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1 [preauth]
debug2: host key algorithms: ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519 [preauth]
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com [preauth]
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com [preauth]
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1 [preauth]
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1 [preauth]
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com [preauth]
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com [preauth]
debug2: languages ctos:  [preauth]
debug2: languages stoc:  [preauth]
debug2: first_kex_follows 0  [preauth]
debug2: reserved 0  [preauth]
debug2: peer client KEXINIT proposal [preauth]
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,ext-info-c [preauth]
debug2: host key algorithms: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-ed25519,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa [preauth]
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc [preauth]
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc [preauth]
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1 [preauth]
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1 [preauth]
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib [preauth]
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib [preauth]
debug2: languages ctos:  [preauth]
debug2: languages stoc:  [preauth]
debug2: first_kex_follows 0  [preauth]
debug2: reserved 0  [preauth]
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256 [preauth]
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 [preauth]
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none [preauth]
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none [preauth]
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_INIT [preauth]
debug2: monitor_read: 6 used once, disabling now
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1 [preauth]
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks [preauth]
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent [preauth]
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS [preauth]
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received [preauth]
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0 [preauth]
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks [preauth]
debug1: KEX done [preauth]
debug1: userauth-request for user michele service ssh-connection method none [preauth]
debug1: attempt 0 failures 0 [preauth]
debug2: parse_server_config: config reprocess config len 370
debug2: monitor_read: 8 used once, disabling now
debug2: input_userauth_request: setting up authctxt for michele [preauth]
debug1: PAM: initializing for "michele"
debug1: PAM: setting PAM_RHOST to "192.168.56.5"
debug1: PAM: setting PAM_TTY to "ssh"
debug2: monitor_read: 100 used once, disabling now
debug2: monitor_read: 4 used once, disabling now
debug2: input_userauth_request: try method none [preauth]
debug1: userauth-request for user michele service ssh-connection method password [preauth]
debug1: attempt 1 failures 0 [preauth]
debug2: input_userauth_request: try method password [preauth]
debug1: PAM: password authentication accepted for michele
debug1: do_pam_account: called
Accepted password for michele from 192.168.56.5 port 60904 ssh2
debug1: monitor_child_preauth: michele has been authenticated by privileged process
debug1: monitor_read_log: child log fd closed
debug1: temporarily_use_uid: 1004/1004 (e=0/0)
debug1: ssh_gssapi_storecreds: Not a GSSAPI mechanism
debug1: restore_uid: 0/0
debug1: PAM: establishing credentials
User child is on pid 4618
debug1: SELinux support disabled
debug1: PAM: establishing credentials
debug1: permanently_set_uid: 1004/1004
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: ssh_packet_set_postauth: called
debug1: Entering interactive session for SSH2.
debug2: fd 6 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug2: fd 8 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: server_init_dispatch
debug1: server_input_channel_open: ctype session rchan 0 win 1048576 max 16384
debug1: input_session_request
debug1: channel 0: new [server-session]
debug2: session_new: allocate (allocated 0 max 10)
debug1: session_new: session 0
debug1: session_open: channel 0
debug1: session_open: session 0: link with channel 0
debug1: server_input_channel_open: confirm session
debug1: server_input_global_request: rtype no-more-sessions@openssh.com want_reply 0
debug1: server_input_channel_req: channel 0 request pty-req reply 1
debug1: session_by_channel: session 0 channel 0
debug1: session_input_channel_req: session 0 req pty-req
debug1: Allocating pty.
debug2: session_new: allocate (allocated 0 max 10)
debug1: session_new: session 0
debug1: SELinux support disabled
debug1: session_pty_req: session 0 alloc /dev/pts/1
debug1: server_input_channel_req: channel 0 request env reply 0
debug1: session_by_channel: session 0 channel 0
debug1: session_input_channel_req: session 0 req env
debug2: Setting env 0: LANG=it_IT.UTF-8
debug1: server_input_channel_req: channel 0 request shell reply 1
debug1: session_by_channel: session 0 channel 0
debug1: session_input_channel_req: session 0 req shell
Starting session: shell on pts/1 for michele from 192.168.56.5 port 60904 id 0
debug2: fd 3 setting TCP_NODELAY
debug1: Setting controlling tty using TIOCSCTTY.
debug2: channel 0: rfd 11 isatty
debug2: fd 11 setting O_NONBLOCK
```

and for client side:

```
~$ ssh -p 9001 -vv michele@192.168.56.4
OpenSSH_7.5p1 Ubuntu-10ubuntu0.1, OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug2: resolving "192.168.56.4" port 9001
debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to 192.168.56.4 [192.168.56.4] port 9001.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/michele/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/michele/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/michele/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/michele/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/michele/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/michele/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/michele/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/michele/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.5p1 Ubuntu-10ubuntu0.1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.5p1 Ubuntu-10ubuntu0.1
debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.5p1 Ubuntu-10ubuntu0.1 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Authenticating to 192.168.56.4:9001 as 'michele'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: local client KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,ext-info-c
debug2: host key algorithms: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-ed25519,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: languages ctos: 
debug2: languages stoc: 
debug2: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: reserved 0 
debug2: peer server KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1
debug2: host key algorithms: ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: languages ctos: 
debug2: languages stoc: 
debug2: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: reserved 0 
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:ycCOVyRMzFst+8uwleIs1VtvhsoN+3GZE/Tjj7i/MlA
debug1: checking without port identifier
debug1: Host '192.168.56.4' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/michele/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: found matching key w/out port
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: pubkey_prepare: ssh_get_authentication_socket: Permission denied
debug2: key: /home/michele/.ssh/id_rsa ((nil))
debug2: key: /home/michele/.ssh/id_dsa ((nil))
debug2: key: /home/michele/.ssh/id_ecdsa ((nil))
debug2: key: /home/michele/.ssh/id_ed25519 ((nil))
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521>
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-keyex
debug1: No valid Key exchange context
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-with-mic
debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
No Kerberos credentials available (default cache: FILE:/tmp/krb5cc_1002)

debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
No Kerberos credentials available (default cache: FILE:/tmp/krb5cc_1002)

debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /home/michele/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/michele/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/michele/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/michele/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug1: Next authentication method: password
michele@192.168.56.4's password: 
debug2: we sent a password packet, wait for reply
debug1: Authentication succeeded (password).
Authenticated to 192.168.56.4 ([192.168.56.4]:9001).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug2: channel 0: send open
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: network
debug1: client_input_global_request: rtype hostkeys-00@openssh.com want_reply 0
debug2: callback start
debug2: fd 3 setting TCP_NODELAY
debug2: client_session2_setup: id 0
debug2: channel 0: request pty-req confirm 1
debug1: Sending environment.
debug1: Sending env LANG = it_IT.UTF-8
debug2: channel 0: request env confirm 0
debug2: channel 0: request shell confirm 1
debug2: callback done
debug2: channel 0: open confirm rwindow 0 rmax 32768
debug2: channel_input_status_confirm: type 99 id 0
debug2: PTY allocation request accepted on channel 0
debug2: channel 0: rcvd adjust 2097152
debug2: channel_input_status_confirm: type 99 id 0
debug2: shell request accepted on channel 0
Welcome to Ubuntu 17.10 (GNU/Linux 4.13.0-39-generic x86_64)

 * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com
 * Management:     https://landscape.canonical.com
 * Support:        https://ubuntu.com/advantage


0 pacchetti possono essere aggiornati.
0 sono aggiornamenti di sicurezza.

Failed to connect to http://changelogs.ubuntu.com/meta-release. Check your Internet connection or proxy settings

Last login: Sat May  5 12:45:11 2018 from 192.168.56.5
Environment:
  LANG=it_IT.UTF-8
  USER=michele
  LOGNAME=michele
  HOME=/home/michele
  PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
  MAIL=/var/mail/michele
  SHELL=/bin/bash
  SSH_CLIENT=192.168.56.5 60904 9001
  SSH_CONNECTION=192.168.56.5 60904 192.168.56.4 9001
  SSH_TTY=/dev/pts/1
  TERM=xterm-256color
  XDG_SESSION_ID=39
  XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/1004
  DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:path=/run/user/1004/bus
```

From the client side, it seems there is a GSSAPI failure about the credentials. I would like to ssh in my server withouth typing the password. Can you help me, please? Thansk!

Comment: looks like you forgot to get a ticket as user michele. Try running "kinit" and then ssh again.

Comment: I have just tried, but ssh still asking for password. `micheleclient@client:~$ sudo kinit michele
[sudo] password di micheleclient: 
Password for michele@SERVER.COM: 
micheleclient@client:~$ sudo klist -ef
Ticket cache: FILE:/tmp/krb5cc_1002
Default principal: michele@SERVER.COM

Valid starting       Expires              Service principal
07/05/2018 09:43:48  08/05/2018 09:43:48  krbtgt/SERVER.COM@SERVER.COM
 Flags: FPI, Etype (skey, tkt): aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96, aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96 
micheleclient@client:~$ ssh michele@server.com
michele@server's password: `

Comment: I also made same changes: adding the row default_ccache_name = /tmp/krb5cc_1002 in the krb5.conf file to force the access to that cache, and verified the permission on that file: `micheleclient@client:/tmp$ ls -l krb5cc_1002
-rw------- 1 root root 695 mag  7 09:43 krb5cc_1002
` and  looking at ssh debug I get: `Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
No Kerberos credentials available: Credentials cache permissions incorrect (filename: /tmp/krb5cc_1002)
` before askin for password. Something went wrong with credentials.

Comment: You should not use sudo with kinit, just kinit. It should be owned by your own user.

Comment: Well, I used sudo just because the user registered in the SERVER.COM (my realm) realm is michele (michele@SERVER.COM) and not micheleclient. By typing su michele, and using kinit (without sudo) I get `michele@client:~$ kinit
Password for michele@SERVER.COM: 
kinit: Failed to store credentials: Internal credentials cache error (filename: /tmp/krb5cc_1002) while getting initial credentials
`

Comment: of course, because the file is owned by root now. Remove it and try again please.

Comment: you mean, remove the /tmp/krb5cc_1002 file stored on the client machine?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77150/discussion-between-michele-ub-and-sebastian-stark).

Comment: Don't use sudo. Just `kinit michele` and then try again. Any user can request tickets for another user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message indicates that you do not have a valid TGT ("Ticket Granting Ticket") for the user you are trying to connect with. You need to run "kinit" first. This will try to get a TGT from the kerberos server and place it in the ticket cache (`/tmp/krb5cc_1002` in your case).

You should not do this using *sudo*, as it will create the ticket cache with the wrong permissions. If you did it with sudo you should remove the ticket cache with the wrong permissions (`sudo rm /tmp/krb5cc_1002`) and try running `kinit` again as normal user.

Something not directly related to this issue but worth mentioning: You do not need to add users to `/etc/krb5.keytab`, like you seem to have tried according to your `klist -ke` output. This file is for host/service authentication only. Users need only be added to the kerberos server (*KDC*).